# Android studio endless compilation

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, compilation

One time my android studio ran into endless compilation, and from then on that version of kotlin jvm plugin is always with endless compilation. Yesterday, that bug appears again with another version of kotlin jvm plugin. Two versions are invalid now and there must be more and more. Reinstalling or invalidating caches doesn't help. Could someone help?

Comment: Open the `Build` window and see if there are any error messages in there. You also might want to look into removing any `.lock` files in the `*username*/.gradle` folder (if a file has been locked and not released it could stall out the build) and maybe deleting the contents of `*username*/.gradle/caches`. These are just things that sometimes work for people though - look at the build output to see if there are any clues, you might be able to gt more specific advice

Comment: In my logs: [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] ran into recycled 'waiting to acquire lock', 'lock acquired', and 'releasing lock'. I tried deleting file folders '.gradle/caches', '.gradle' and '.android', which didn't help.

Comment: I don't know if those lock messages point to a problem, acquiring then releasing them is what *should* happen. It's when a lock can't be acquired (because there's a lockfile that wasn't deleted) that you can get problems. I don't really know enough to suggest anything else, sorry - you could take a look here if you're using Windows: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#optimize-studio-windows especially the part about adding exclusions to your antivirus - maybe a large file is causing it to stall

Comment: I found both intellij idea and android studio can't build projects with kotlin 1.7.10 and 1.7.20 on my mac. There must be some shared configuration files of these two applications. I tried deleting folders '.m2' and '.knoan' which didn't help. And I dare not delete other folders.

Comment: Have you seen the *Troubleshooting* section of the Gradle docs? (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/troubleshooting.html) You might find something in there - and they have a link to their help forum at the bottom, you might have more luck there since they're Gradle specialists! You could also try making sure you're online (or set Gradle to offline mode), and maybe try building from the command-line to see if that works (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline). It's possible the Gradle installation itself is messed up too (since that's shared) but I'm guessing